# angular rxjs subscription teardown

Tags: angular, rxjs

There are different patterns for tearing down subscriptions in angular components. I've been using the `Subject` / `takeUntil` pattern, in this form:

```typescript
export class FooComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
...
  source$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(...);
...
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }
}
```

Today I've been told to add another line to the `ngOnDestroy`:

```typescript
this.destroy$.complete();
```

After doing a bit of research, it does show up on some online examples and not in others, but either way I'm failing to see the point. Looking at the source code of [Subject.complete](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L83) it will loop through any inner observers and complete these. Assuming we don't subscribe to the `destroy$` subject directly, isn't this list of inner observers always supposed to remain empty? If that's the case isn't that call to `this.destroy$.complete()` redundant?

Comment: https://twitter.com/Michael_Hladky/status/1193641068635590656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `complete()` if you're using `destroy$` only for `takeUntil()` operators.

When `destroy$` emits `next` `takeUntil()` will complete the chain that will also unsubscribe from `destroy$` and thus there will be no subscribers so `complete()` should not be necessary.

Btw, I've seen people using `complete()` in this situation as well. I can't find any example right now but in contrast [`ngrx/component-store` is just calling `next()`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/a9e7fb177c4750ac5c8a39ea3898454669cde847/modules/component-store/src/component-store.ts#L72).

Comment: I am just calling a complete as a good habbit.